# Why is my margin-top not working the way it should be?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently building my own website and i have trouble with a div and its margin porperty.
If i set margin-top from the googleDiv to 100% the div moves to the ultimate end of the page instead to the end of its parent-div.

HTML:

```
<div id="scrollspy2">
        <div id="test"><img id="facebook" src="facebook.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" data-animation="true" title="facebook"></div>
        <div id="twitterDiv"><img id="twitter" src="twitter.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="twitter"></div>
        <div id="googleDiv"><img id="googleplus" src="google+.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="google+"></div>

    <div class="container" id="customContainer">
            <div class="row">
                <div class=" col-md-12 col-md-offset-3">
                    <header>
                            <h1 style="font-size:1050%;"><u>Hi!</u></h1>
                            <h1 style="font-size:300%;">*** <strong>***************</strong>.</h1>
                    </header>
                    <p style="font-size:150%;">******* <strong>**********</strong> *********************</p>
                    <p style="font-size:130%;">************************************************ </p>
                    <button id="button1" class="btn btn">**********</button>
                    <p id="or">or</p>
                    <form class="displayinline"action="Contactfile.html">
                            <button id="button2" class="btn btn">******* *****</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$("#scrollspy2").css("height",$(window).height());
```

Comment: Please post your CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are exactly stuck on. From what i think it is the div collapsing. Hence why it is going outside its parent element.

Please import this ID element with the googleDiv ID leaving space in between

```css
#group:after{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

So put the ID "group" next to GoogleDiv inside the div element, preventing it to collapse

Answer (score 0):

Margins are great, but it takes some getting used to. You can define them in all kinds of measurements, like px, % etc.

The proble here is, dat you have a font with a font-size of 1050%. That is 10,5 times the height and width of your screen. Or to say as large as your house.

A margin is the space that is reserved at the outside of the box, like padding is for the inside of the box. If you put a 100 percent margin on a side of the box, the browser is trying to push the box as far as itcan push it to the side or the bottom of the screen. Because 100% is the total width or height of your screen.

If you want a small space between two elements, try 20px instead of 100%

Comment: well the thing is i am currently doing the css for the desktop/laptop version and when i take a look at the site on my laptop the googleDiv is not visible. But it should be. Dunno why the Googlediv is moving out of his parent div

Comment: Could you post the code on fiddler or something like that. That would make it way easier to determin what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Place those 3 divs into its own row with col-md-12 or col-md-4 each one in its own; and maybe even a container.

Otherwise a `<div class="clearfix"></div>` after your 3 special ones might fix it.